# How to make a rectangle as per dimension given by any user?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I was trying to make a rectangular shape, as per the value entered inside the input area.
To be more specific, I have two fields:

**Width:**

**Height:**

So, I wanted to pass the value of width and height to a function in JavaScript and make the rectangle as per values entered.

I tried looking up the internet, but even after spending hours on it, I could not find a solution. :(
Any help will be appreciated.

P.S. a small fiddle or example will be helpful.

Comment: Please try search again. Using keywords "javascript draw rectangle" gives a lot of hits...

Comment: What have you tried? Make an attempt and post that code so we can help you fix it. Hint: you'll need to read the value of a textbox, have an element (div or span) for the box and set its width and height its in css. That should give you some keywords to search at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html body:

```
<input type='text' id='w'>
<input type='text' id='h'>
<input type='submit' id='go'>
<div id='shape'><div>
```

js:

```
  $(function(){
        $('#go').click(function(){
          $('#shape')
            .css('width',$('#w').val())
            .css('height',$('#h').val())
            .css('border','2px solid black');
        });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LAtNC/

It simple you just need to set some css property for a 'div' and of course, check your input, it is just an example.

Answer (score -1):

What did you look up the internet?

you can get values of height, width text boxes using jQuery val()

```
$('#ID').val();
```

Then set the values retrieved to your element

```
$('#element').css('height',height_from_text_box);
$('#element').css('width',width_from_text_box);
```

Comment: -1 'What did you look up the internet?' is a comment not an answer

Comment: @JohnJohnGa I asked that question because probably he didn't look up in the right direction. If he knew basics of javascript well (that it gets data from DOM and puts to DOM), he'd have asked a more specific question with attempted code.

Comment: @YogeshSawant I agree, I should have been more specific. Probably, I did not try looking up in the right direction.

Comment: @user1838946 I didnt mean any offence to you mate. I hope none is taken.

Comment: @YogeshSawant None is taken. :)